# idf vs relative frequency to extract important words for a corpus

Tags: python, r, text-mining, tf-idf, trend

I am new to text mining. I am trying to extract important words out of a given corpus of documents. I am debating on whether I should use the `idf score` or `relative frequency` to detect important words for a corpus. By important words, I mean the words that best represents the corpus.

As far as I understand, `idf score` would be useful to detect `rare words` and not `important words`. Therefore, I am leaning towards the `relative frequency` of the word to determine it's importance in the corpus but I am not sure.

I am curious to know in more detail the difference in usage of these two scores. Or is there a better way to extract out important words out of corpus?

Comment: "the" has a high relative frequency in most corpora, is it an important ? it depends what you're doing. Usually tf-idf is used, not idf, which indeed is higher when the term is rarer

Comment: Thanks for reply. My input is coming from an algorithm which uses NLP and word2Vec to come up with a relevant list of words. So, input will not have such words like "the".  AFAIK, `tf-idf` comes into play for a single document. Here, I want to find important words for a corpus.

Comment: if you don't have any corpus to compare yours too, I guess the best you can do is term frequency of document frequency, and remove stopwords (including "the"), another possibility is to find lists of terms associated with a frequency "in the language" (i.e. in a corpus that reflects most books, or spoken language, or movies), and divide your frequencies by those, the highest ratios would point to the "most important terms"